# Oozie jobs with fork and not using join

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am creating a work flow in which i need to fork 3 jobs, which would execute independently. I don't have need to join. 
Is there any way to achieve this in oozie?
is join mandatory with fork??

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.5_Fork_and_Join_Control_Nodes)

> The fork and join nodes **must** be used in pairs. The join node assumes
>   concurrent execution paths are children of the same fork node.'

Also the docs state that,

Oozie performs some validation for forked workflows and doesnt allow the job to run if it violates. However, if you want the behaviour you can disable forkjoin **validation** so that Oozie will accept the workflow.

For specific workflow, set `oozie.wf.validate.ForkJoin` to `false` in the job.properties file.
For all workflows, set `=oozie.validate.ForkJoin=` to `false` in the oozie-site.xml file

Also, IMPO you can just `join` and then progress to the `end` node.

Comment: @Suvama Pattayil I have a specific problem Could you please have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289788/how-to-get-shell-script-logs-in-hdfs-while-scheduling-with-oozie`

Comment: @Active_user Hey u removed ur qn?

Comment: Sorry I had to changed the whole question. So, I deleted the question. Please have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456565/how-to-execute-parallel-jobs-in-oozie`